# Select fragment to show in ViewPageAdapter based on boolean condition

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-tablayout, android-viewpager2

I am creating some simple Android app with Kotlin. I am using TabLayout in my MainActivity and I want to select a fragment to show according to some condition set during login to the app.

Here is `MainActivity.kt`

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    ...

    tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabLayout)
    viewPager2 = findViewById(R.id.viewPager)
    myViewPagerAdapter = MyViewPagerAdapter(this)

    viewPager2.adapter = myViewPagerAdapter

    tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(object : TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener {
        override fun onTabSelected(tab: TabLayout.Tab) {
            viewPager2.currentItem = tab.position
        }
        override fun onTabUnselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab) {}
        override fun onTabReselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab) {}
    })

    viewPager2.registerOnPageChangeCallback( object: ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {
        override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) {
            super.onPageSelected(position)
            tabLayout.getTabAt(position)!!.select()
        }
    })

    ...
```

and `MyViewPageAdapter.kt`

```
class MyViewPagerAdapter(fragmentActivity: FragmentActivity) :
    FragmentStateAdapter(fragmentActivity) {
    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return 5
    }

    override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
        return when(position){
            0 -> HomeFragment()
            1 -> SystemFragment()
            2 -> DockerFragment()
            3 -> TerminalFragment()
            4 -> SettingsFragment()
            else -> HomeFragment()
        }
    }

}
```

maybe showing what I want to do with code would be simpler than explaining it.

```
override fun createFragment(position: Int, condition: Boolean): Fragment {
    return when(position){
        0 -> HomeFragment()
        1 -> SystemFragment()
        2 -> if (condition)
        {
            DockerFragment()
        }
        else
        {
            OtherFragment()
        }
        3 -> TerminalFragment()
        4 -> SettingsFragment()
        else -> HomeFragment()
    }
}
```

Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 0):

This is my temporarry solution to this problem. I don't have better idea. I renamed `MyViewPagerAdapter` to `DockerViewPagerAdapter` and created a duplicate `YunohostViewPagerAdadpter` where I simply changed that one line with `DockerFragment()` to `YunohostFragment()`. And that is implementation for now in `MainActivity`

```
when (sharedPref.getString("server_type", "")) {
        "docker" -> {
            viewPager2.adapter = DockerViewPagerAdapter(this)
        }
        "yunohost" -> {
            viewPager2.adapter = YunohostViewPagerAdapter(this)
        }
        else -> {
            throw Exception("ServerType value not permitted")
        }
    }
```